# Numeros primos/ pares e impares C

Tags: c

Quiero realizar un programa en **C** en el que se pida ingresar números hasta que se ingrese un "0" o un número negativo, cuando esto ocurra el programa debe mostrar:

1. Cuántos números se ingresaron
2. Cuántos números son primos
3. Cuántos números son pares
4. Cuántos números son impares

He realizado prácticamente cada inciso por separado, pero no se como podría poner todo en un mismo programa.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n, i, flag = 0;

    printf("Teclea un numero entero positivo: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=2; i<=n/2; ++i)
    {
        if(n%i==0)
        {
            flag=1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (flag==0)
        printf("%d SI es un numero primo.",n);
    else
        printf("%d NO es un numero primo :(",n);
        getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*He realizado prácticamente cada inciso por separado*" sin embargo no lo has compartido, o al menos yo no lo veo. ¿Dónde está el resto del código?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías usar algo asi:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int esPrimo(int n)
{
    int i, cant = 0;
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if(n % i == 0)
            cant++;
    }
    if(cant == 2)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    int cantNum = 0, cantPrimos = 0, cantPar = 0, cantImpar = 0;

    printf("Teclea un numero entero positivo: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while (n > 0)
    {
        cantNum++;
        if(n % 2 == 0)
            cantPar++;
        else
            cantImpar++;
        if (esPrimo(n))
            cantPrimos++;
        printf("Teclea un numero entero positivo: ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
    }
    printf("Cantidad de numeros ingresados: %d\n", cantNum);
    printf("Cantidad de numeros primos: %d\n", cantPrimos);
    printf("Cantidad de numeros pares: %d\n", cantPar);
    printf("Cantidad de numeros impares: %d\n", cantImpar);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Señor, Muchisimas gracias, me ha sacado de un aprieto. ! Gracias Totales

Comment: De nada. Si te sirvió la respuesta marcala como aceptada :). Saludos.

Comment: Deberías evitar responder a preguntas que, de una forma o de otra, te piden que les hagas los deberes... les haces un flaco favor dándoles la respuesta masticada. Una cosa es que tengan un algoritmo que no funcione porque tiene errores y otra es que te presente, literalmente, un main vacío.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tienes que agregar es un bucle para que repita todo el proceso que ya tienes, en este ejemplo estoy utilizando un bucle `while`, aunque también podrías utilizar un `do-while`.

```
while (n > 0) {
//realizar proceso
}
```

Tu código quedaría:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int n=1, i, flag = 0;
  while (n > 0){
    printf("Teclea un numero entero positivo: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=2; i<=n/2; ++i)
      {
        if(n%i==0)
          {
            flag=1;
            break;
          }
      }

    if (flag==0)
      printf("%d SI es un numero primo.",n);
    else
      printf("%d NO es un numero primo :(",n);
    getch();
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**Nota**: inicialicé la variable `n` para que puede entrar al bucle.